# how to add textbox value to dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html

I have one Dropdown list it has some values and other option,when i select other option it shows textbox ,i have to enter some text into it ,so i want to add that value to dropdown lilst,so how can i solve this?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html> 
    <head>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckColors(val){
     var element=document.getElementById('color');
     if(val=='pick a color'||val=='others')
       element.style.display='block';
     else  
       element.style.display='none';
    }




    </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
      <select name="color" onchange='CheckColors(this.value);'> 
        <option>pick a color</option>  
        <option value="red">RED</option>
        <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
        <option value="others">others</option>
      </select>
    <input type="text" name="color" id="color" style='display:none;'/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: using html and javascript only.

Comment: On which event you want to do this manipulation ? Do you mean you want that `other` option for future users ?

Comment: You want to create a new option node from the text input?

Comment: whatever inserting in other option with textbox that value has to add on dropdown menu list.

Comment: I think @RayonDabre means what event do you want to use to add the new option. for example you can have an add button, after you click it, it trigger the click event and add the new color to options. there has to be an event for you to add the new color in a callback function

Comment: above example dropdown list has ,red ,blue, suppose i want pink color so i have add that value in others option(using textbox), and add that value in dropdown list,(red,blue,pink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a button, get `select` value to check if it's `others` or `pick` / display the button according to it.

To add a new element, create an `option` and add it inside the select with `x.add(option);`

```
function CheckColors(){
var element = document.getElementById("mySelect");
var element2 = document.getElementById("color");
var element3 = document.getElementById("addColor");
 if(element.value =='pick a color'|| element.value =='others'){
   element2.style.display='block';
   element3.style.display='block';
 }
 else {
   element2.style.display='none';
   element3.style.display='none';
  }
}

function addValue(){
  var textToAdd  = document.getElementById("color").value;
  var x          = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var option     = document.createElement("option");
  option.text    = textToAdd;
  x.add(option);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7woyyw4h/

Comment: Also add `value` for options!

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code hope it will helpful for you.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnAddToBegining').click(function(){
      var data = $("#txtAdd").val();
      $("#ddlList").prepend("<option value='0' selected='selected'>"+ data  +" </option>");
    });

     $('#btnAddToEnd').click(function(){
        var data = $("#txtAdd").val();
        $("<option value='6'>" + data +"</option>").appendTo("#ddlList");
    });       
});
</script>

<select id="ddlList">
  <option value="1">ASP.NET</option>
  <option value="2">C#</option>
  <option value="3">VB.NET</option>
  <option value="4">HTML</option>
  <option value="5">jQuery</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="txtAdd" />

<br/><br/>
<input type="button" id="btnAddToBegining" Value="Add Item to Begining" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" id="btnAddToEnd" Value="Add Item to End" />
```